# Как в SQLite правильно выполнить запрос с условием?

Tags: база-данных, sqlite3

Имеем запрос, в котором нужно заполнить поля в БД значениями из переменных (var...)

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO dbname(col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (var1, var2, var3, var4))

db.commit()
```

Как сделать чтобы запрос не выполнялся, если значение var1 уже существует в col1 ?

Знаю, что нужно использовать условие WHERE... но как его использовать правильно в этом запросе, не могу понять (только учусь), подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Сделать col1 уникальным или первичным ключом и использовать какой-нибудь `INSERT OR IGNORE`?

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
-- Дает возможность обновить данные в случае совпадения ключа
-- Предположим что ключ col1
INSERT INTO dbname(col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
on conflict (col1) do update 
    set 
        col2 = excluded.col2, 
        col3 = excluded.col3, 
        col4 = excluded.col4;


-- Работает так-же как INSERT or IGNORE
INSERT INTO dbname(col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
on conflict (col1) do nothing;

-- Ну и собственно
INSERT or IGNORE INTO dbname(col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);
```